# Import library creation not working

Tags: winapi, ld

I am trying to link a small DLL (just one input file) on Windows using binutils ld version 2.21. I am getting the following error for every symbol marked as `dllexport` in my object file:

```
Cannot export <symbol name>: symbol not found
```

What can I do about this? I have verified through application of nm that the problem symbols are present and are non-static, yet I am still getting the error. I have also tried deleting and rebuilding the object file; it didn't help. I suspect that the problem has to do with my linkline. For the record, here it is:

```
clang++ -fPIC -Wl,--dll,--compat-implib,--nxcompat,--dynamicbase -shared \
-o pthread.dll pthread.o -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is apparently due to a bug in Clang. The workaround I developed was to:

1. Remove all the `__declspec(dllexport)` (but not the `__declspec(dllimport)`) statements from the source code.
2. Recompile the libraries dependent on `pthread.dll`. Even though there isn't an import library anymore, GNU ld is smart enough to generate one on the fly, thanks to the `__declspec(dllimport)` statements in my source code.